# What's the "supported" way of using Exchange PowerShell cmdlets in a script?

Tags: exchange, powershell

From what I've read, Microsoft doesn't support using the Exchange PowerShell cmdlets from anywhere but the Exchange Management Shell. However, surely people need the ability to script things and run them non-interactively? I've tried looking around, but all I can find is that "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.E2010" isn't a supported method, with no mention of what *is* supported. Does anyone know? Or does everyone just ignore Microsoft and use Add-PSSnapin anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the TechNet article [Scripting with the Exchange Management Shell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123798(v=exchg.141).aspx), all you need to do is set up the environment with the following statements:

```
. 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
```

Assuming that `D:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server` is the Exchange installation folder on the machine